# Ngrok and npm explaination Wix API AuthO

Tags: npm, ngrok, velo

Am working on a API with Wix, and ive been able to get everything working, But there is one eliment i cannot automate or account for because i have no idea how its working or understand it properly.

I have been following: https://dev.wix.com/api/rest/tutorials/create-your-wix-app

It advises me to use Ngrok and also Npm after downloading some sample skd.

WHen setting up the App, it asks for a Redirect URL (When users authorize your app, we’ll redirect them to this URL with a temporary authorization code.)

It also asks for: App URL (When users start to add your app from the Wix App Market, we’ll redirect them to this URL.)

What i cannot understand is how Ngrok allows and uses the urls in the tutorial
As there is no physical files for these calls?
https://<NGROK_STRING>.ngrok.io/login  and  https://<NGROK_STRING>.ngrok.io/signup

I peronsally thought it was just a URL it called and passed back the Auth code, So i created a PHP page that fetched the string behind code: in the url so it can email me or save to file,
But this just does not work.

(I have it working in ngrok and npm, but i cannot have these running every time a user wants to download the app and link into our system)

I cannot understand the use of npm and ngrok, am presuming there is some sort of handshake somewhere.
Is this the correct way, do i have to install these programs on the a dedicated server and have them running at all time incase someone installs the app?

Is it not possible to just have the AUth code sent to me so i can finish the setup, generate a refresh token and be done with all the ngrok and npm

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. So I'm gonna explain NPM and NGROK quickly.

**NPM = node package manager** -
npm is simply a package manager, so you can use it if you like to. Especially with node.js you are most likely gonna be using it. But with PHP npm might be used in your development enviroment so for example PHPStorm to get the packages you need. So no direct connection to WIX.

**NGROK** -
Is used to redirect traffic from a semi-permanent ngrok URL to a likely dynamic IP like from your Computer. In my case I work on localhost, and NGROK just relays the calls from wix to my localhost where the application is running. This is needed, since stuff from the internet can not simply access a computer. That's what NGROK is for.

If you have a ready application, you should not need ngrok, aslong as you have it running on a server somewhere. "Just" replace your NGROK urls with the actual URLs of your server.

I hope this helped =)